# How to get the previous Monday 2-00 a.m.?

Tags: java, date, time, jodatime

I'm in Java 7.

I'm pretty new with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and would like to ask a simple question. How to get the previous Monday 2-00 a.m. Date? I mean this:

```
____________________________________________________________________________
                              Week 1                          |   Week 2    |
______________________________________________________________|_____________|
 MONDAY       TUESDAY WENDSDAY THURSDAY FRIDAY SATURDAY SUNDAY|  MONDAY ... |
2-00 a.m.                                                     | 2-00 a.m.   |
______________________________________________________________|_____________|
```

So, I need to return `Week 1`'s Monday 2-00 a.m.
 ***iff*** the current time is between the `Week 1`'s Monday 2-00 a.m. and the `Week 2`'s Monday `2-00 a.m.`.

Is there a relatively simple way to achieve that via Joda-Time?

Comment: Have you mixed a.m. and p.m. in your question? It is a bit confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a solution in Joda-Time. Second, a similar solution in the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later, intended as the successor to Joda-Time. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Both the solutions below follow similar logic which is comprehensively summarized as follows. [Joda DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) and [Java8 LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) provide immutable datetime implementations using the [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). To get to Monday 2am of the last week you can take the following steps chaining subsequent calls using the fluent interface:

1. Get current time on the past Monday by subtracting the difference between day of the week and Monday using [LocalDateTime.minus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#minus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) method
2. Subtract today milliseconds to get to past Monday 00:00am
3. Add 2 Hours using [LocalDateTime.plus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) method.

## Joda-Time

```
    DateTime currentTime = new DateTime();
    DateTime dateResult;
    boolean shouldReturnLastMonday = (currentTime.getDayOfWeek() != DateTimeConstants.MONDAY ||
            currentTime.hourOfDay().get() < 2);
    if (shouldReturnLastMonday) {
        dateResult = currentTime.minus(Days.days(currentTime.getDayOfWeek() - DateTimeConstants.MONDAY))
                .minus(currentTime.getMillisOfDay())
                .plus(Hours.hours(2));
    } else {
        dateResult = currentTime.minus(currentTime.getMillisOfDay())
                .plus(Hours.hours(2));
    }
    System.out.println(dateResult);
```

## java.time

```
  LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();
  LocalDateTime dateResult;
  boolean shouldReturnLastMonday = (currentTime.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.MONDAY) ||
                                    (currentTime.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.MONDAY && currentTime.getHour() < 2);
  if(shouldReturnLastMonday) {
      dateResult = currentTime.minus(currentTime.getDayOfWeek().getValue() - DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getValue(), ChronoUnit.DAYS)
              .minus(currentTime.getLong(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY), ChronoUnit.MILLIS)
              .plus(2, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
  } else {
      dateResult = currentTime.minus(currentTime.getLong(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY), ChronoUnit.MILLIS)
              .plus(2,ChronoUnit.HOURS);
  }
```

Comment: Is it possible with Java 7 or I need JodaTime in this case?

Comment: I have added a Jodatime solution, this can be done in Java 7 too but the jodatime or java 8 api are much cleaner

Comment: I feel that this answer is good, but could warrant more explanation as to the mechanical process behind it.

Comment: @vsnyc This Answer is quite helpful but would be improved with some discussion or explanation. StackOverflow is meant to be more than code-snippet library.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, will add some explanation shortly.

Comment: I have added further explanation, hopefully it would be sufficient to the reader.